# UITableView checkmark for only selected row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

The problem I have is that;

I use table view in the application and I want checkmark to be generated next to each selected row. But checkmark is also generated in the rows of other sections except for the row in the section where the page is scrolled down. However, when I print the clicked cell, the result is correct.

This is my code to create a checkmark:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)

    let row = indexPath.row
    let indexpath = NSIndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section: indexPath.section)

    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexpath as IndexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    currentCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray 

    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark             

    for organ in self.dataSource.organs {
        if(organ.name == organName) {
            for sympton in organ.symptonList {
                if (sympton.name == self.symptonName ){
                    self.symptonList.append(sympton.questionList[indexPath.section].question  + " " + sympton.questionList[indexPath.section].answerList[row].lowercased())
                    print("*******")
                    print(sympton.questionList[indexPath.section].question  + " " + sympton.questionList[indexPath.section].answerList[row].lowercased())
                }
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

My cellForRowAt method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
    let row = indexPath.row
    for organ in self.dataSource.organs {
        if(organ.name == organName) {
            for sympton in organ.symptonList {
                if(sympton.name == symptonName) {
                    cell.textLabel?.text = sympton.questionList[indexPath.section].answerList[row]
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return cell

}
```

It is very useful for me if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Please post your cellForRowAtIndexPath method as the problem is in it, not in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Ok, I posted also cellForRowAtIndexPath method in below @Miknash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add array of IndexPaths in your view controller:

```
var selectedIndexes: [IndexPath] = [IndexPath]()
```

Then your didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
    if let index = selectedIndexes.index(where: {$0.row == indexPath.row && $0.section == indexPath.section}){
        selectedIndexes.remove(at: index)
    }
    else {
        self.selectedIndexes.append(indexPath)
    }

    for organ in self.dataSource.organs {
        if(organ.name == organName) {
            for sympton in organ.symptonList {
                if (sympton.name == self.symptonName ){
                    self.symptonList.append(sympton.questionList[indexPath.section].question  + " " + sympton.questionList[indexPath.section].answerList[row].lowercased())
                    print("*******")
                    print(sympton.questionList[indexPath.section].question  + " " + sympton.questionList[indexPath.section].answerList[row].lowercased())
                }
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
    let row = indexPath.row
    for organ in self.dataSource.organs {
        if(organ.name == organName) {
            for sympton in organ.symptonList {
                if(sympton.name == symptonName) {
                    cell.textLabel?.text = sympton.questionList[indexPath.section].answerList[row]
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(self.selectedIndexes.contains(where: {$0.row == indexPath.row && $0.section == indexPath.section})) {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray 
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark             
    }
    else {
         cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
         cell.accessoryType = .none             
    }
    return cell

}
```